# Query taking more time from .net client than from query window

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a very strange situation. When i run a store procedure from SQL Management studio it works as expected and takes only 1 second to return the information. If i made exactly the same call from a .net method on IIS it takes more than a minute to complete. I ran a trace and it freezes on the call to the stored procedure

GetConConsultaCuenta_Mov '20150901 00:00:00','20150930 00:00:00',4896,168123,0,1,0,0,0,'0'

I use very simple code to fill the data

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, con);
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 5000000;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    con.Open();        
    da.Fill(ds);

    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
    da.Dispose();
    con.Dispose();
```

The IIS is local so is not a matter of the data traveling

Comment: You removed some of the code here to make it obfuscated for posting. Where is the command type, command text and parameters? Have you explored the possibility of parameter sniffing? Here is an excellent article on that topic. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/

Comment: Could be one of a number of things, In SSMS you are ready have an open connection so there is no time used there. also in SSMS you are mor lightly to hit the cache when rerunning commands as your status is identical to the last time you ran the command. In SSMS you will get results as they are found so it may look quicker but takes just as long to get all the data.

Answer (score 0):

You're not just measuring the time to get back the first record, you're filling a data adapter.  Depending on how much data is coming back, and the complexity of your meta-data, that could take quite some time.

Try temporarily changing your code to simply iterate the result

```
IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read());
```

rather than filling the data adapter.  See how that time compares.

On a side note, you will not dispose of your IDisposable resources (cmd, con) if an Exception is thrown.  Use the `using` keyword to ensure proper resource cleanup.

Comment: same result.. for a strange reason the execution is delayed:

Comment: DateTime T1 = DateTime.Now;
       using( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
       {
           con.Open();
           using(SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql,con))
           {
               SqlDataReader dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
               while (dr.Read()) ;

           }
       }

       DateTime t2 = DateTime.Now;
       TimeSpan Tt = t2 - T1;
       return Tt.TotalSeconds;

Comment: If he wants the QUERY time, don't record the `connection.Open()` time. Running the Stored Procedure directly versus running it from code should be an apples to apples comparison. The Open will add time to the code as suggested by @LeonardoPerez. Also, should use Stopwatch object, not DateTime. Stopwatch object is much more accurate for tracking a time span/event length.